# PHP Cookies using in colorbox

Tags: php, cookies, colorbox, setcookie

I create a cookie in login.php

```
setcookie("mes_mod_kull",$userid,time() + 3600,'/');
```

I have a link for open colorbox like this :

```
<a href="file_add.php" class="colorbox">Add File</a>
```

In file_add.php I have to use cookie. I mean, I have to reach to cookie which I was created in login.php

I use this code for test cookie value : `print $_COOKIE["mes_mod_kull"];` But there is an error here : Notice: `Undefined index: mes_mod_kull in..........`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Do you have any output before `setcookie`? `Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script`

Comment: Make sure `$userid` is set and has some value or else the cookie won't get set.

Comment: @MihaiIorga I know, so `print` is top of the page any other outputs.

Comment: @DainisAbols   I tested it before, I'm sure it has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in setcookie function. It's need to define domain.

I change the following code

```
setcookie("mes_mod_kull",$userid,time() + 3600,'/');
```

to

```
setcookie("mes_mod_kull",$userid,time() + 3600,'/','mydomain.com');
```

and it's worked. It's little bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your print call is in the SAME script as the setcookie, you'll have to wait until the NEXT execution of the script for $_COOKIE to be populated with that new cookie. PHP builds/populates the superglobal (_GET, _POST, _COOKIE, etc...) **ONCE** while the script is initialization, then does not touch them again for the life of the script. setcookie update $_COOKIE for you.